# Bootstrap Responsive Tables with "display: table" body element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

To get my layout to stretch to a full page, I'm using [Sticky CSS Footers](http://pixelsvsbytes.com/blog/2011/09/sticky-css-footers-the-flexible-way/). This approach requires me to set the html Body to "display: table".

Everything works fine except for the responsive tables in Bootstrap. These still stretch out past the display window.

Here's an example: http://jsbin.com/wifomelabu/1/edit?html,css,js,output (minimize the browser to see the problem)

If you remove "display: table" from the body it works fine.

Is there any way to get the responsive tables to work with the "display: table" body element? Or do I have to find a new way to stretch my layout to a full page?

Comment: Hmm.  I've NEVER seen the `body` set to `display: table`.  Is that on purpose?

Comment: Yup! It allows you to create "rows" so the page can go the full height of the browser window: http://pixelsvsbytes.com/examples/sticky-footers-the-flexible-way/simple.html

Comment: Hmm.  Just use `width:100%`, and then put a `<table>` into the body.  I think that THAT may be your problem ...

Comment: @god-is-good can you elaborate / do a fiddle or something?

Comment: Are you trying to get a sticky footer? Or are you looking to fill the full screen height with your layout?

Comment: @ckuijjer - I'm trying to fill the full screen with my layout. I'm only using the terminology "sticky footer" because that's the terminology used in the article I referenced: http://pixelsvsbytes.com/blog/2011/09/sticky-css-footers-the-flexible-way/

Comment: The problem with `display: table` is that tables keep expanding to allow their children to fit. Can't you simply set `height: 100%` to for example the `.container`? Like http://jsbin.com/bufezureqi/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
td {
  width: 100px;
}
```

instead of

```
td {
  min-width: 100px;
}
```

See this example
http://jsbin.com/jesitabiya/1/